# MYSQL user datable mess up

Tags: mysql

I tried to allow root remote access in MYSQL,
I did
update host='*" where user='root' and host='localhost';
then restarted the mysql server,
now I have not localhost/remote access!!
any idea to revert this change? please help
thanks!

Edit: resolved
I use usr/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking & 
to bypass grant table that I messed up, then reverted the changes I made.

Comment: What exactly is the error message?
And how did you update those information about user and host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the the procedure [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) to reset your root account.  After that, you may want to restore the database named `mysql` from your recent backup if your changed broke any of the other permissions.