# Grant root access without having grant access with mysql

Tags: mysql, permissions, root, password-reset

In attempts to learn more about apache and mysql, I've been fiddling with my local environment. Fun times. Of course, this leads to my screwing things up. So, thanks for being there.

Recently, I messed up a bit in mysql. I currently don't have a root user, and the users I do have don't have grant access. So, I can create users and all that, but I can't create a root user with super powers.

Besides removing and reinstalling mysql, is there a way to grant a user total access in my current situation?

Comment: Just restore from your backup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Completely reset mysql server authentication](http://serverfault.com/questions/143619/completely-reset-mysql-server-authentication)

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/143619/completely-reset-mysql-server-authentication http://serverfault.com/questions/86587/what-is-my-mysql-root-password http://serverfault.com/questions/75401/mysql-user-datable-mess-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to reinstall MySQL. You can just create a new root user and reset the permissions in MySQL as described in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html.